# Verticepair - route matrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

I have the following problem. I have two lists:

`list1` defines all possible commodities in a network g. E.g. Form vertex `1` to vertex `2`.

```
list1 = {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},....}
```

`list2` defines all possible routes from vertex `x` to vertex `y`.
E.g.:

- r1 could be from vertex 1 to vertex 2 and the route would be 1,2
- r2  then could be 1,3,2 etc

For example:

```
list2 = {{1,2},{1,3,2},{1,4,3,2},{},{},{}}
```

Now, I would like to construct a commodity-route incidence matrix `H`, which will be `1` if e.g. the elements from List one represent the first and the last element of `list2`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you wrote, the problem should be trivial, since the commodity-route incidence matrix `H` will consist of a single row of ones, and zeros everywhere else. The location of this single row of ones will be the index of `{x,y}` in `list1`. Thus, no computation is needed at all, since you already chose `x` and `y` in the construction of `list2`, which furthermore makes the computation of `list2` redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way to do it:

```
L1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
L2 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3, 2}};
Outer[Boole[#1 == #2[[{1, -1}]]] &, L1, L2, 1]
```

which produces

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$

which shows that the computation of `L2` is redundant, since the position of the row of ones is uniquely determined by the initial choice of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Works perfectly.